# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id:[] error on deployment of test class to UAT

Tags: unit-test, deployment

I am trying to deploy the test class to UAT, the test class is working fine dev and have 100% coverage. But when the same test class in deployed to UAT I am getting INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY. Do any one help me with this error.

Apex class

```
public with sharing  class CC_ReopenCaseStatusUpdate_LT {

@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String, String> updateCaseRemoteAction(Case theCase){
   
    Map<String, String> status = new Map<String, String>();
    status.put('status', 'error');
    status.put('message', '');
    CaseService.caseIdsWithActiveAgentWorks.add(theCase.Id);        
    try{           
        //dme : PARXIMPL-6088 : Allow 3rd level user to Reopen any case
        if (UserService.isThirdLevelAgent()){
            status = CC_WithoutSharingHandler_LT.updateCases(theCase);            
        }else{
            //RemoteObjectController.updat(type, recordIds, localFields);
            theCase.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            update theCase;
            status.put('status', 'success');
        }
    }catch (DmlException ex) {
        status.put('message', ex.getDmlMessage(0));
    }
    
    return status;
}}
```

Test class

```
 @isTest
 public class CC_ReopenCaseStatusUpdate_LT_Test {

@isTest static void updateCaseRemoteActionTest(){
    
    Case case1 = TestUtil.createCase( CaseService.getDefaultServiceCountryCode(), CC_CaseConstants.CASE_ORIGIN_GROUP_WEBFORM, false);
    case1.CC_SPProcessCancelled__c = true;
    case1.Status = 'Closed';
    insert case1;

    Test.startTest();
        case1.Status = 'In Progress';
        Map<String, String> result = CC_ReopenCaseStatusUpdate_LT.updateCaseRemoteAction(case1);
        System.assertEquals(result.get('status') , 'error', result.get('message'));
    Test.stopTest();
}

@isTest static void updateCaseRemoteActionWithOutSPCancelTest(){
    Case case1 = TestUtil.createCase( CaseService.getDefaultServiceCountryCode(), CC_CaseConstants.CASE_ORIGIN_GROUP_WEBFORM, false);
    case1.Status = 'Closed';
    insert case1;

    Test.startTest();
        case1.Status = 'In Progress';
        Map<String, String> result = CC_ReopenCaseStatusUpdate_LT.updateCaseRemoteAction(case1);
        System.assertEquals(result.get('status') , 'success', result.get('message'));
    Test.stopTest();
}

@isTest static void updateCaseRemoteActionExceptionTest(){
    
    Case case1 = TestUtil.createCase( CaseService.getDefaultServiceCountryCode(), CC_CaseConstants.CASE_ORIGIN_GROUP_WEBFORM, false);
    case1.CC_SPProcessCancelled__c = true;
    case1.Status = 'Closed';
    insert case1;
    
    String profilePattern = '%' + UserService.THIRD_LEVEL_AGENT_PNAME_SUFFIX;
    String profileName = [SELECT Name FROM Profile WHERE Name LIKE :profilePattern LIMIT 1].Name;
    User thirdLvlUser = TestUtil.createUser(profileName, null, false);
    thirdLvlUser.Username = 'thirdLevelagent@test.com';
    thirdLvlUser.CC_CaseRole__c = 'Lidl EU CC 3rd Level Support User';
    thirdLvlUser.ServiceCountryCode__c = CaseService.getDefaultServiceCountryCode();
    insert thirdLvlUser;
    
    Test.startTest();
    System.runAs(thirdLvlUser){
        case1.Status = 'In Progress';
        Map<String, String> result = CC_ReopenCaseStatusUpdate_LT.updateCaseRemoteAction(case1);
        System.assertEquals(result.get('status') , 'error', result.get('message'));
    }
    Test.stopTest(); 
}   

@isTest static void updateCaseRemoteActionWithOutSPCancelExceptionTest(){
    
    Case case1 = TestUtil.createCase( CaseService.getDefaultServiceCountryCode(), CC_CaseConstants.CASE_ORIGIN_GROUP_WEBFORM, false);
    case1.Status = 'Closed';
    insert case1;
    
    String profilePattern = '%' + UserService.THIRD_LEVEL_AGENT_PNAME_SUFFIX;
    String profileName = [SELECT Name FROM Profile WHERE Name LIKE :profilePattern LIMIT 1].Name;
    User thirdLvlUser = TestUtil.createUser(profileName, null, false);
    thirdLvlUser.Username = 'thirdLevelagent@test.com';
    thirdLvlUser.CC_CaseRole__c = 'Lidl EU CC 3rd Level Support User';
    thirdLvlUser.ServiceCountryCode__c = CaseService.getDefaultServiceCountryCode();
    insert thirdLvlUser;
    
    Test.startTest();
    System.runAs(thirdLvlUser){
        case1.Status = 'In Progress';
        Map<String, String> result = CC_ReopenCaseStatusUpdate_LT.updateCaseRemoteAction(case1);
        System.assertEquals(result.get('status') , 'success', result.get('message'));
    }
    Test.stopTest(); 
}}
```

[image]

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  What troubleshooting have you done?  Have you checked sharing and permissions on the Case object and record types in production?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running as admin user? It looks like an issue with the related records.
I would check the record that is being inserted on Line 254 in AgentWorkServiceCreateAgenetWorkForInProgressCase and see whether the current user has permissions to all the references on that record.

Answer (score 0):

Check the records you are inserting to see if they have any hard coded IDs.  Those IDs may be valid in your current org, but are not valid in UAT.

Things to look for are user IDs, record type IDs, etc.

Look in the TestUtil class which builds these records, and trace from there.